# how to prevent data duplication in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to insert only unique data into SQLite, so i found in android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) that i can use `insertWithOnConflict(table, nullColumnHack, contentValue, ignore_conflict)` but it works exactly as the regular `insert();` . honestly, I did not understand `nullColumnHack` I tried null and my column name but still the same result, please help

this is my code

```
public void insertNewList(String list_name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DB_COLUMN, list_name);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(DB_TABLE, null, cv, db.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

    }
```

`DB_TABLE` is my table name which is: lists_name

Comment: What do you mean by unique data? Should the whole row be unique? [Does this answer your question](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: @MatiasLappalainen I only have list_name in my data, I'm trying to prevent two lists from having the same name.